# What are the effects of keeping a clumping bamboo in a pot permanently?

Tags: container-gardening, bamboo

I'm looking at buying a couple of 15 gallon [*Bambusa multiplex*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bambusa_multiplex) "Green Hedge" for privacy but want to keep them both contained and with the option of moving them around as other plants mature.

If I place them in a half whiskey barrel from Home Depot (approximately 27 gallons):

- Will it restrict how much they will grow vertically?
- How long should they be able to survive in a contained space?
- Is it possible for "parts" to fall of and spawn new plants outside of the container? I wouldn't think so but I want to verify.
- Is there anything specific I should do to ensure successful growth?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know - I have a runner (*Phyllostachys* - possibly *aureosulcata* "spectabilis" but ID is dubious) that's been in a 16 gallon pot (indoors) for several years. Given the climate here, it has grown taller than the parts that are still outdoors, since the top growth gets killed every winter and those plants have increased slowly as a result. On the other hand it's clearly potbound and has put up only one new shoot for a few years now. It's 16-18 feet tall, the ones it was dug up and potted from outside are up to about 8 feet now (they were closer to 4 when it was potted from one of the shoots in an undesirable location.)

The pot (a thick ceramic one) has so far remained unbroken. I'm guessing at least 4 years, could be longer.

Comment: I am curious - when a bamboo plant becomes 'pot bound' does this mean it simply stops making new clums but continues growth on existing clums?

Answer (score 2):

They'll bust through. You need to dig out rhizomes to manage a bamboo border.

Comment: Are you saying the rhizomes will bust through the barrel? What if I keep elevated, will I still have the same risk?

Comment: They'll still bust through the barrel yes. It's not risk unless you are unable to do the leg work later.

Comment: I don't think they'll bust through unless the barrel is rotten.